# Passing Two different Object type to a single Method in Java?

Tags: java, android, oop, object, smartcard

I try to follow this Stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777384/method-accepting-two-different-types-as-parameter) but it was not helping my purpose what I wanted to achieve. I want to know is it achievable in Java. Here is the problem statement. I tried to look into Java reflection, Haskel Either, etc. but it endup having two different objects.

I have two type of objects.

1. > com.mobilesecuritycard.openmobileapi.Session msc_session;
2. > org.simalliance.openmobileapi.Session sim_session

I want to have a method which accepts any of the two objects given above.

For example

```
public void runOperation(Object activeSession) {

activeSession.openLogicalChannel(APPLET_AID);
-- do the rest of operations ---
}
```

I want to use that function as given below

```
if(isSetSIMSessionTrue()){
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Using SIM Session as its True");
    sim_session = getSim_session();
    runOperation((org.simalliance.openmobileapi.Session) sim_session);
} else{
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Using MSC Session as its false");
    msc_session = getMSCSession();
    runOperation((com.mobilesecuritycard.openmobileapi.Session) msc_session);
}
```

I can even receive correct object class using

```
String classNameToBeLoaded = activeSession.getClass().getName();
```

But still not able to get object properties to activeSession object.

Is there any way to pass either of the session object to the runOperation method and only use activeSession for doing rest of the operation. As both objects has same methods and functionality but access different secure element on a android device. So, I do not want to write two different runOperation() method for the different objects. To be more precise, is it possible to cast an object type to another object. I am not sure about this. Any pointers or help will be grateful. I hope, I made my point clear what I want to achieve.

PS: please ignore syntax as I am just providing some code snippets to make my question clear.

Comment: Down voted for what? Is it not a valid programming question?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this with reflection or even just `instanceof`, but why? Why not use overloading? Define two methods:

```
public void runOperation(com.mobilesecuritycard.openmobileapi.Session session) {
}

public void runOperation(org.simalliance.openmobileapi.Session session) {
}
```

If the goal is to reduce code duplication, then use a single method but have it take the least common ancestor superclass of the two types of sessions, which is hopefully not `Object`:

```
public void runOperation(SessionSuperclass session) {
  // do something that can work with any type of session
  doSomethingMoreSpecific(session);
}
```

And if necessary, implement two versions of `doSomethingMoreSpecific()`. That would be the object-oriented way of doing things, not `instanceof` or reflection.

Comment: I used instanceOf but I think you did not get my question. I donot want to have two runOperation() method. That could be the simplest and obvious solution which I do not want. I donot want to duplicate the function.

Comment: I updated my answer in light of your comment. I would discourage you from using `instanceof` and a bunch of `if` statements because that's not object-oriented. What happens if all of a sudden you need to support a third type of session? Will you add another `if`? That's not maintainable. Type-specific behavior should be expressed using the appropriate language constructs, such as method overloading.

Comment: Thanks. Yup. I think I have to write two separate functions taking into consideration from yours and others reply and based on my research on the Internet. But it will endup having two different app packaged inside one android apk which I was trying to avoid. :-|

Answer (score 0):

```
if(activeSession instanceof com.mobilesecuritycard.openmobileapi.Session) {
    // some stuff
} else if(activeSession instanceof org.simalliance.openmobileapi.Session) {
    // some other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this check in your `runOperation()`.

```
if(activeSession instanceof org.simalliance.openmobileapi.Session){
    // Type 1
}
else if(activeSession instanceof com.mobilesecuritycard.openmobileapi.Session){
    // Type 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution that springs to mind is to have both of the objects implement a common interface.

**For example**

```
public interface ObjectIF
{
    public void doSomething();
}
```

Have some classes that implement the interface:

```
public class ClassOne implements ObjectIF
{
    public void doSomething() { // Code }
}

public class ClassTwo implements ObjectIF
{
    public void doSomething() { // Code }
}
```

Now with your method you can do something like this:

```
public void doSomethingWithObject(ObjectIF object)
{
    // Provided an object implements the interface, it can be passed here.
    object.doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to cast an object type to another object?

Yes, you can [cast](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

You can check and cast:

```
if(activeSession instanceof org.simalliance.openmobileapi.Session){
    org.simalliance.openmobileapi.Session mySession = (org.simalliance.openmobileapi.Session) activeSession 
}
else if(activeSession instanceof com.mobilesecuritycard.openmobileapi.Session) {
    com.mobilesecuritycard.openmobileapi.Session mySession = (com.mobilesecuritycard.openmobileapi.Session) activeSession 
}
```

Comment: thanks. I already tried this but mySession object doesnot gives mySession.openLogicalChannel(ID) as given by msc_session or sim_session object gives. i.e msc_session.openLogicalChannel(ID). Not working in my context

Comment: So cast to an object who does have openLogicalChannel function

Comment: I am afraid that will not help as mySession object has nothing in it. Tried this too already. :-|