# Passing object of multiple types as parameter to a method

Tags: java

Since Java 7, we can catch multiple exceptions in the same catch clause like the following.

```
try { 
  ...
} catch( IOException | SQLException ex ) { 
  ...
}
```

Similarly, Is there any way to implement like the following without using Inheritance?

```
public void passMultipleTypes(Type1 | Type2 obj) {
  ...
}
```

The `obj` object can either be `Type1` or `Type2`. **I do not want to use inheritance here as these classes are generated and I cannot change them**. So I cannot define them as

```
public class Test1 extends CommonSuperClass {
  ...
}
```

`Type1` and `Type2` have similar attributes. So I was thinking of working with `obj` like the following.

```
public void passMultipleTypes(Type1 | Type2 obj) {
  System.out.println(obj.getCode());
  System.out.println(obj.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777384/method-accepting-two-different-types-as-parameter

Comment: @Daneel I don't think so OP can opt for solution you suggested. The classes are generated and to implement an interface for both classes might be difficult.

Comment: Check generics type.

Answer (score 1):

Since classes are generated as part of some code gen plugin.

You can use composition along with inheritance to solve this issue.

Write wrapper class for Type1 and Type2 extending to common interface.

This will provide code reusability as well as act as a layer between apllicaton code and 3rd party API.

```
public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Processor processor = new Processor();
        processor.passMultipleTypes(new Type1Wraper());
        processor.passMultipleTypes(new Type2Wrapper());

    }

}

interface BasicType {

    void operationOne();

    void operationTwo();

}

class Type1 {
}

class Type2 {
}

class Type1Wraper implements BasicType {

    private Type1 type;

    @Override
    public void operationOne() {

        // type 1 method

    }

    @Override
    public void operationTwo() {

        // type 1 method

    }

}

class Type2Wrapper implements BasicType {

    private Type2 type;

    @Override
    public void operationOne() {

        // type 2 method

    }

    @Override
    public void operationTwo() {

        // type 2 method

    }

}

class Processor {

    public void passMultipleTypes(BasicType object) {

        object.operationOne();
        object.operationTwo();

    }
```

Comment: May I ask how can we access methods of `Type1` and `Type2` in `passMultipleTypes(T obj)`

Comment: Type1 and Type 2 should  implement a common interface. Just added in my answer.

Comment: Then this can be achieved without introducing generics. Let classes `Type1` and `Type2` implement common interface and `passMultipleTypes(BasicType type) `

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to use inheritance, you could use method overloading.

```
public void passMultipleTypes(Type1 obj) {
  ...
}

public void passMultipleTypes(Type2 obj) {
 ...
}
```

If you pass an argument of Type1, the first method would be called. If the argument is of Type2, the second would be called.

Comment: Yes, it would. But the question says the classes cannot be modified. This was the only other way.

Comment: Well yeah. I have the current method in your style. I asked this question so that I could avoid duplication :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change classes `Type1` and `Type2` then just use overloading of method:

```
 public void passMultipleTypes(Type1 obj) {
   System.out.println(obj.getCode());
   System.out.println(obj.getValue());
 }

 public void passMultipleTypes(Type2 obj) {
   System.out.println(obj.getCode());
   System.out.println(obj.getValue());
 }
```

"But code duplicates...." yes, that is right. There will be some duplicates of code. But because you cannot change original code then you cannot solve it in nice way. Just move duplication to another place.

Comment: Well. The sole purpose of this question was to avoid duplication. :-)

Comment: I know, but not with limitation of "cannot change code".

Answer (score 0):

You can define a cutom type like `Either` class in `Scala`:

```
class Or<L,R>
{
    private final Optional<L> left;
    private final Optional<R> right;

    ...
}
```

So you can use this class like this:

```
public void passMultipleTypes(Or<Type1, Type2> obj) {
  if(obj.isLeft()) {

  } else {

  }
}
```