# Java how to make a method argument accept subclass type and superclass

Tags: java, oop, generics, inheritance, subclassing

I have a superclass and one subclass with some variables like below:

```
public class A{
    
    private int first;
    private int second;
    
    public A(int _first, int _second){
        first = _first;
        second = _second;
    }
    
    public int getFirst(){
        return first;
    }
    
}

public class B extends A{
    
    private int third;
    
    public B(int _first, int _second, int _third){
        super(_first, _second);
        third = _third;
    }
    
    public int getThird(){
        return third;
    }
    
}
```

I want to build a method in the main class that accepts a generic argument that can be of type `A` or type `B` like below:

```
public class Main{

    public int val = 2;

     public static void main(String []args){
        A a = new A(1, 2);
        B b = new B(1, 2, 3); 

        printObject(a);
        printObject(b);

     }
     
     public void printObject(A a){
         
         int f = a.getFirst() * val;
         int s = a.getSecond() * val;
         
         if(a instanceOf B){
             int t = a.getThird() * val; // compiler does not find the getThird() method this way
         }
     }
}
```

How can this be achieved?. is generics an option? I have thought about making `printObject()` method inside `A` then override it inside `B` however I have some other variable like `val` above that I am creating in main.

### update

I tried to use `instanceOf` like the above method. But this way the compiler does not find the subclass's specific method.

Comment: What should that script do in case of A object is of type A? What should `t` contain then?

Comment: there is an if condition like in the comment. "if object is an instance of B ... a.getThird".  I guess the relevant question is can a method attribute accept both type A (superclass) and type B (subclass) ?

Comment: Please try to write some code that covers this. I don't think that generics help you out here - please have a look at the concept of generics and edit your question to cover when you've seen any connection between your question and generics

Comment: I did not mean that generics is the only option for me. whatever works is fine. I think this is quite a reasonable question. How can I write a method that accepts any type within the base class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method accepting two different types as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777384/method-accepting-two-different-types-as-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, by definition, if you declare A as a parameter to any method and B is it's sub-class, then any A or B can be passed to that method.

You *could* then achieve what you want using the instanceof operator (to check if the parameter passed in is of type B). However, inheritance / method override should typically be used rather than instanceof.

You could pass 'val' into the printObject() methods on A/B. If several variables like 'val' are involved you could pass in another object or perhaps you need to split your code across multiple methods on class A (overridden in B), passing in different values as appropriate? (You wouldn't normally do calculations in a method whose purpose is to print an object but perhaps that was just an example?)

Answer (score 0):

Everything is much simplier) You could get rid of this method in the main class, cause it's producing some redundant coupling. And all this `instanceof` really smells in 2019. You could make it more independent.

Class A:

```
public class A{

    private int first;
    private int second;

    public A(int _first, int _second){
        first = _first;
        second = _second;
    }

    public int getFirst(){
        return this.first;
    }

    public int getSecond(){
        return this.second;
    }

    public void print(int multiplier) {
        System.out.println(this.first * multiplier);
        System.out.println(this.second * multiplier);
    }

}
```

Class B:

```
public class B{

    private int third;

    public B(int _first, int _second, int _third){
        super(_first, _second);
        third = _third;
    }

    public int getThird(){
        return this.third;
    }

    @Override
    public void print(int multiplier) {
        super.print(multiplier);
        System.out.println(this.third * multiplier);
    }

}
```

Class Main:

```
   public class Main{

         public int val = 2;

         public static void main(String []args){
            A a = new A(1, 2);
            B b = new B(1, 2, 3); 

            a.print(val);
            b.print(val);

         }
   }
```

Comment: I get that. It is just that the print method is more complicated than that. I am actually on the android platform and the print method is actually updating a view's elements (like text and images) according to the values of either the subclass or the superclass

Comment: Hm..So, main idea here is to encapsulate all object-specific logic inside this object. If this method is complicated than you probably need to review your app architecture. Of course, you can resolve your issue simply with all this 'instanceof' and other workarounds, but it will definitely lead you to the spaghetti-code and really tight coupling. It will be really hard to maintain in the future, so, I would highly recommend to think about architecture.

Comment: If @user7331538 is using the MVP-Pattern, then the Model should not contain any logic about how to "print" or "show" itself, this is code that should be in the View! I was searching for a similar problem :-(

Answer (score 0):

Writing object oriented code is more than extending a class , your API's and other functionality should be designed as part of the solution.

In your case, the most appropriate way to do this is to add the print method to the object itself, you can either override the entire function or to call the super class inside the overriding class.

```
public class A{
    /// ... your code

 public void print(){
    System.out.println("first :"+first+", second : "+second);
}
}

public class B extends A{
     /// ... your code
    public void print(){
       //Option A - use parent class getters/setters to implement print for object B
       System.out.println("first :"+super.getFirst()+", second : "+super.getsecond() +" third" + third);
      }

      //Option B (More usable to methods returning a value or performing an update) - Perform operation on parent variables, then perform on class specific variables       
       super.print()
       System.out.println("third : "+third);
    }    


}
```

and then

```
A a  = new A();
A b = new B();

a.print();
b.print();
```

Will each call the correct runtime function based on their actual implementation